# how can i stop microphone from listening and break process loop if no response is there from user for a given second in gcp speech to text

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am using an example given in GCP documentation and using  API to convert speech to text. I need to stop the loop when the user dont response for 2  to 3 second. How can i achieve this. I didnt get any function to control it . I used time function but didnt help.

The example is in https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/samples/speech-transcribe-streaming-mic

```
  RATE = 16000
    CHUNK = int(RATE / 10) 
    
    class MicrophoneStream(object):
        """Opens a recording stream as a generator yielding the audio chunks."""

    
        
            
    def listen_print_loop(responses):
       
        num_chars_printed = 0
        for response in responses:
            if not response.results:
                continue
               result = response.results[0]
            if not result.alternatives:
                continue
                # Display the transcription of the top alternative.
            transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript
    
            overwrite_chars = " " * (num_chars_printed - len(transcript))
    
            if not result.is_final:
                sys.stdout.write(transcript + overwrite_chars + "\r")
                sys.stdout.flush()
    
                num_chars_printed = len(transcript)
            #elif time idle
    
            else:
                print(transcript + overwrite_chars)
    
                # Exit recognition if any of the transcribed phrases could be
                # one of our keywords.
                if re.search(r"\b(exit|quit)\b", transcript, re.I):
                    print("Exiting..")
                    break
    
                num_chars_printed = 0
    
    
    def main():
    
        os.environ = credentials_STT()
         
        language_code = "en-IN"  
        client = speech.SpeechClient()
        config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
            sample_rate_hertz=RATE,
            language_code=language_code,
        )
    
        streaming_config = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
            config=config, interim_results=True
        )
    
        with MicrophoneStream(RATE, CHUNK) as stream:
            audio_generator = stream.generator()
            requests = (
                speech.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
                for content in audio_generator)
    
            responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)
    
            # Now, put the transcription responses to use.
            listen_print_loop(responses) # function called
            print("end")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add option `single_utterance = True` so that when there is no speech detected, it will automatically end the recognition. But take note that this option is usually used for **short statements**. For more information about this option, you can check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#streaming-requests).

You can check the usage of it in the [speech to text python reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/speech_v1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1.types.StreamingRecognitionConfig).

Your `streaming_config` should look like this:

```
        streaming_config = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
            config=config, interim_results=True, single_utterance=True
        )
```

Comment: The microphone is now terminating but I cant exit the loop .. any suggestion how can i achieve that.

Comment: @SouravRoy Which loop are you pertaining to?

Comment: listen_print_loop(responses) # function called << this loop. Even when microphone stops this function keeps holding up expecting to  to receive something.. However i solved it by    if not response.results:        break but this is sometime breaking off without any reason